# Dúvida - inserir elemento no fim da lista - (Python)

Tags: python

Sou novo por aqui e estou aprendendo agora Python. Tenho uma dúvida aqui de como que faz pra inserir um elemento no final da lista. Pesquisei na internet como que faz pra inserir algum elemento no final da lista, e vi que utiliza o método append(). Mas como sou iniciante ainda, não sei se está correto como estou fazendo...

```
class LL:

    def__init__(self).inicio = None

    def taVazia(self): return self.inicio is None

    def insereInicio(self, item):

        temp = Noh(item)
        temp.setProx(self.inicio)
        self.inicio = temp

    def insereFim(self, item):
        temp = Noh(item)
        temp.setAnterior(self.fim)
        self.fim = temp
        append(novoItem)
```

Answer (score 3):

Então Leonardo, você precisa de chamar a função **.append()** após a variável lista, dessa forma(No Python 3):

```
lista = [1,2,3,4,5]
print(lista)    # Resultado: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

lista.append(6) # Resultado: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
print(lista)
```

Comment: Ok. Vou fazer assim!

Answer (score 0):

O método `.append()` cria um espaço que vai ser a ultima posição da lista.

Ex.:

```
lista = [1, 2]
lista.append(3)  #resultado: [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Dei uma pequena reformulada na sua publicação. Se achar indevido, pode reverter na [revisão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/369134/revisions). (apesar de ser a mesma solução do colega acima)

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o método `.append()`

```
arr = [1, 2, 3]

arr.append(4)  # [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

como listas são estruturas heterogeneas, você pode armazenar `strings` (palavras ou texto em termos simples). Utilizando a mesma lista:

```
arr.append("olá")  # [1, 2, 3, 4] antes do comando ser executado
print(arr)  # [1, 2, 3, 4, "olá"]
```